# сложить массивы

Tags: php, массивы

Имеется 3 массива следующего вида:

```
array(
  array(10,10,10),
  array(10,10,10),
  array(10,10,10),
  array(10,10,10)
);
array(
  array(20,20,20),
  array(20,20,20),
  array(20,20,20),
  array(20,20,20)
);
array(
  array(30,30,30),
  array(30,30,30),
  array(30,30,30),
  array(30,30,30)
);
```

Требуется получить 1 переменную в которой будет находиться сумма всех значений со всех массивов. Т.е. в данном случает 720.

Только начал изучение. Прошу сильно не пинать, а помочь и если не трудно объяснить, как это делается. Заранее всем низкий поклон.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если положить все 3 массива в еще один массив, то можно, например, использовать [array_walk_recursive](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-walk-recursive.php):

```
<?php

$sum = 0;
$ar = array( 
  array(
    array(10,10,10),
    array(10,10,10),
    array(10,10,10),
    array(10,10,10)
  ),
  array(
    array(20,20,20),
    array(20,20,20),
    array(20,20,20),
    array(20,20,20)
  ),
  array(
    array(30,30,30),
    array(30,30,30),
    array(30,30,30),
    array(30,30,30)
  )
);

array_walk_recursive(
    $ar,
    function($v) use (&$sum) {
        $sum += $v;
    }
);

echo $sum;
```

[Вот](https://ideone.com/wf7PZX) Ваши 720 =)

Comment: ух ты. спасибо. я даже не предполагал о существовании такого метода. я все думал куда - то в сторону перебора массива через какой нибудь foreach. Большое спасибо.

Comment: @Денис Через двойной `foreach` тоже можно, но будет менее красиво выглядеть код.

Comment: понял, спасибо. А через foreach как бы вы это сделали? Я немного заплутал сам, сначала пытался их смержить в один массив, а потом через один foreach получил сумму в каждом массиве, через array_sum($array). После чего заблудился и собственно решил написать сюда)) Ваше решение явно лучше, тем более я узнал для себя "новый путь" и теперь изучу получше этот метод - спасибо. Но очень интересно как это можно было бы решить еще.

Comment: @Денис Я не пишу на `PHP` уже много лет, поэтому, вероятно, мой код будет хуже, чем у человека, который его активно использует. Но вот придумал, например, что-то такое: https://ideone.com/ZW92PO

Comment: Если вложить три массива в еще один массив, как я сделал в ответе, тогда `foreach` нужно делать тройной, а не двойной. Плюс этот код завязан на структуру входного массива, и если там что-то поменяется, то все сломается. С этой точки зрения использование `array_walk_recursive` делает код менее специфичным.

Comment: спасибо вам огромное. :)